# Want to resize Horizontal StackView that has CollectionView and a Button inside it

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uistoryboard, uistackview

I am using a Horizontal CollectionView and UIButton embedded inside a Horizontal StackView. Button has a fixed Height and Width (say 50 X 50 )I want Stackview Width to be dynamic according to CollectionView contentsize. Please guide me through this.

[This is what I am Getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltdK5.png)

[This is what i want to Achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IHPPE.png)

StackView Width should grow dynamially

Comment: What constraints have you given?

Comment: For StackView I gave : Leading and Top,
        Alignment : Fill,
        Distribution : Fill
        Spacing : 8, Just want button to follow collectionView content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Better way is to add cell in the last index of UICollectionView.

Here is the implementation

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
   return COUNT + 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    if indexPath.row = COUNT{
      return PLUSCELL
    }else{
      return NORMALCELL
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you add "+" button as last cell of CollectionView and set background color to orange for other cells? I think it will be easier.

Comment: I can Add But As per the requirement, depending on number of cells, collectionview should scroll horizontally provided button should remain at fixed position at last

Comment: So, by adding button at last it will be remain at the end of all cells. As per my knowledge, its not possible to do only via a stackView.